# how to efficient compute multi flink stream result from one source

Tags: apache-flink

for example:

There is a video play log, with format as:
 user_id, video_id, play_duration, video_duration, country, request_date

I want to compute:

a. number of play event in last minute

b. number of play event today

c. the top10 most popular video (be played times) in last hour

d. the top10 most active user (play times) in last hour

In above 4 tasks, they consume same source, but with three different time window. 
Are there any efficient solution to fulfill these jobs without start 3 or 4 jobs to duplicate consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single job that splits the stream 4 ways, and then attach one of these window operators to each of the duplicated streams. You can do the splitting with either split/select, or with [side outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/side_output.html).